# how to run a jar file created using intellij 12

Tags: java, macos, jar, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA 12.0.4 on MAC OS X 10.8.3 to create a jar file.

I go to File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> + -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies -> Selected Main Class after browsing -> selected extract to the target jar -> Directory for META-INF automatically gets populated -> OK -> Apply -> OK -> Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build

Now If I try to run jar using:

```
java -jar path_to_jar/jar_file
```

I get this error

> no main manifest attribute, in path_to_jar/jar_file 
>   $ java -version 
>   java version "1.7.0_17" 
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Any pointers, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look on similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166633/main-class-not-found-intellij-building-a-jar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly.

Answer (score 21):

To fix this issue do two things:

move META-INF in to src/main/resources

then: file-> open module settings

choose artifacts, remove your current one and create a new one, but this time, instead of choosing "extract to the target jar", choose "copy to the output directory and link via manifest"

for the path to META-INF, put the path of the resources dir above that you copied META-INF in to..

now build your artifact

im terminal, go to dir where jars have been produced and to run do:

java -jar yourjarfile.jar

have fun

Comment: April 2017 and this still solves the solution for me. Well done sir

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was because IntelliJ was extracting all the dependencies into the output jar, which ended up overwriting the `/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file with something from one of my included dependencies.

I had to open up the jar and copy in the real `MANIFEST.MF` from the location indicated in the "Manifest File" property that is automatically set in that artifacts page under Project Structure".

Comment: Although this may work surely it's better not to have to open the JAR and hack it about after generating? I followed the instructions from Felbus which fixed it for me without having to hack the jar around

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the "main" class for your jar in order to make it *executable* (i.e. you should point in IDEA on the class which contains `public static void main(String[] args)`

Comment: i did that: Selected Main Class after browsing

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I choose
 File -> Project Structure -> Artifacts -> + -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies -> Selected Main Class after browsing -> copy to the output directoryand link via manifest（extract to the target Jar not working for me） -> Select your project resources folder after browsing for /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF-> OK -> Apply -> OK -> Build -> Build Artifacts -> Build

My Idea version is IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 (Ultimate version) [I read from here](https://www.cnblogs.com/qifengshi/p/6036870.html). It works for me.