# What is the proper way to deploy Java project that has JSON files?

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy the program by making it into an **executable jar** file.
When I run the program directly from IDE (IntelliJ), everything is fine. But after I make **jar** file out of my project, when I run that jar file, I get errors like:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\JsonFiles\Words.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Are you sure your JSON files are bundled within the jar?

Comment: @David Siri Nope. How do I make sure? Can you help me in this one? I configured artifact with "build on make" and run a build on the project as I followed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly

Comment: json files are inside the project folder. So, should they not be bundled automatically when I build artifact?

Comment: That depends how you build your jar. For example, with Maven, only files in `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` are included in the resulting jar by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use relative paths to `src` folder, open an input stream to the file where it's located relative to a class:

```
InputStream in = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("Words.json");
```

where `Words.json` and `SomeClass.java` exists in the same folder/package.