# Exporting and running Intellij .jar projects

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, jar, export

I have exported a Java project using Intellij following the steps in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) question and got a .jar file in `%PROJECT_ROOT%/out/artifacts/ContactRetriever.jar`.
However, when running the .jar file from the command line,

```
java -jar ContactRetriever.jar
```

the following output is given:

```
    Xalan-J command line Process class options:

                            -Common Options-

       [-XSLTC (use XSLTC for transformation)]
       [-IN inputXMLURL]
       [-XSL XSLTransformationURL]
       [-OUT outputFileName]
       [-E (Do not expand entity refs)]
       [-EDUMP {optional filename} (Do stackdump on error.)]
       [-XML (Use XML formatter and add XML header.)]
       [-TEXT (Use simple Text formatter.)]
       [-HTML (Use HTML formatter.)]
       [-PARAM name expression (Set a stylesheet parameter)]
       [-MEDIA mediaType (use media attribute to find stylesheet associated with a d
    ocument.)]
       [-FLAVOR flavorName (Explicitly use s2s=SAX or d2d=DOM to do transform.)]
       [-DIAG (Print overall milliseconds transform took.)]
       [-URIRESOLVER full class name (URIResolver to be used to resolve URIs)]
       [-ENTITYRESOLVER full class name (EntityResolver to be used to resolve entiti
    es)]

(press <return> to continue)
```

The manifest file (`MANIFEST.MF`) of my project contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

`Main` is the main class (entry point).

The layout of the project is:

[image: layout]

The project structure artifacts are:

[image: artifacts]

and the modules:

[image: modules]

Why isn't main being executed?

**Edit:**

The code in main is:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.*;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.Cookie;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.logging.Level;


public class Main  extends Defaults{

    private static WebClient webClient;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0) {
            printUsage();
            return;
        }

        if(args[1] == null)
            initAccounts("");
        else
            initAccounts(args[2]);

        if(args[4] == null || args[6] == null)
            printUsage();
        else
            getContacts(args[4], args[6], 4);

            // initAccounts("");
            // getContacts("C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads", "C:\\Users\\user\\Projects\\ContactRetriever", 4);
    }
}
```

Comment: where exactly is your main class? Usually, you have to provide the full path to the class in the manifest e.g org.yourapp.Main

Comment: Main.class. Isn't it already included in the .jar?

Comment: What i mean is, do you have your main class inside a package, or in the root, right under `src/Main`?

Comment: Under root, path to main:  root --> src --> main --> java --> Main.java

Comment: I see you are using maven, are you packaging your app with `mvn clean package` command?

Comment: No, I don't know whether intellih is invoking maven or not (I do not use mvn from the command line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103827/discussion-between-mateus-viccari-and-sebi).

Comment: @Mateus Viccari Replied in chat

Comment: @Mateus Viccari  Added pom file in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error said, you have a duplicate dependency:
org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
Remove one of the dependencies and your app must run fine.

Then add the configuration for maven to create the manifest file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.specification.version}</source>
                <target>${java.specification.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It still can't find the Main class (+1-ed btw)

Answer (score 0):

I've also met this problem, and i found that Intellij will automatically generate `META-INF/MANIFEST.IF` under `src/main/java`, but it should be under `src/main/java/resources`, just move it to the correct directory. it worked for me.