# Java jar file does not create file in Drive

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have java project with a **PrintWriter** class only

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("F:\\the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
        writer.println("The first line");
        writer.println("The second line");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

whenever i run this script in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.3 it creates a file in F:\ directory.Fine.

But if a build a .jar file in IntelliJ   by [Jar file Create Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

.It created .jar file but clicking it does not create text file in F:\ dir.
I have tried in building it through Maven but does not create text file in F:\.I can not figure out why? help me please.

Comment: Please run the jar in command prompt using `java -jar <jarfilename>` and check is there any exception

Comment: The problem was in java path variable.Java Path was not found.i fixed the path .and it works now thankz @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

Comment: But still i click the jar file but does not create file in F: dir????