# JavaFX: Artifacts exported .JAR file is not executing

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar, javafx-8

I've build a JavaFX project using Intellij Idea. I followed the instructions from here - [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) and exported the .jar file. Here is my project structure and how I configured build paths,

[image]

I tried to execute the jar file by double clicking on it, but it didn't execute. Then I tried to run it through command line and I got the following error-

```
imran@abdullah:~/Idea Projects/JavaFX  Projects/Mukto Bangla Ovidhan Lite/out/artifacts/Mukto_Bangla_Ovidhan_Lite_jar$ sudo java -jar Mukto\ Bangla\ Ovidhan\ Lite.jar 
path to 'resources/ankurdb/bn_words.db': '/home/imran/Idea Projects/JavaFX  Projects/Mukto Bangla Ovidhan Lite/out/artifacts/Mukto_Bangla_Ovidhan_Lite_jar/resources' does not exist
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/home/imran/Idea%20Projects/JavaFX%20%20Projects/Mukto%20Bangla%20Ovidhan%20Lite/out/artifacts/Mukto_Bangla_Ovidhan_Lite_jar/Mukto%20Bangla%20Ovidhan%20Lite.jar!/mukto/bangla/ovidhan/MainUI.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at mukto.bangla.ovidhan.Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mukto.bangla.ovidhan.DatabaseManager.GetResult(DatabaseManager.java:61)
    at mukto.bangla.ovidhan.MainUIController.initialize(MainUIController.java:60)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application mukto.bangla.ovidhan.Main
```

Here is the `DatabaseManager.java` class-

```
package mukto.bangla.ovidhan;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DatabaseManager
{
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement;

    void Connect(String dbURL)
    {
        try{
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:resources"+dbURL);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.setQueryTimeout(30);
            System.out.println("DB Connected.");
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void InsertData(String insertQuery)
    {
        try{
            statement.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void UpdateData(String updateQuery)
    {
        try{
            statement.executeUpdate(updateQuery);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void DeleteData(String deleteQuery)
    {
        try{
            statement.executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    ResultSet GetResult(String resultQuery)
    {
        ResultSet rs=null;
        try{
            rs = statement.executeQuery(resultQuery);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return rs;
    }

    void StopConnection()
    {
        try{
            if(connection != null)
                connection.close();
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `MainUIController.java` class-

```
package mukto.bangla.ovidhan;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class MainUIController implements Initializable {

    DatabaseManager db=new DatabaseManager();
    ObservableList<OvidhanMeaning> MeaningList;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchField;

    @FXML
    private ImageView searchIcon;

    @FXML
    private ImageView aboutIcon;

    @FXML
    private TableView<OvidhanMeaning> ovidhanTable;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<OvidhanMeaning, String> englishCol;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<OvidhanMeaning, String> banglaCol;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        Image search = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/search.png").toString(), true);
        Image about = new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/about.png").toString(), true);
        //Font bnFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResource("/fonts/Siyamrupali.ttf").toExternalForm(), 12);
        Font bnFont = Font.loadFont(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/Siyamrupali.ttf"), 12);

        searchIcon.setImage(search);
        aboutIcon.setImage(about);

        db.Connect("/ankurdb/bn_words.db");
//        db.Connect("/ankurdb/Ankur_DB.db");
        ResultSet rs = db.GetResult("select en_word,bn_word from words");
        MeaningList=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        try {
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String enword = rs.getString("en_word");
                String bnword = rs.getString("bn_word");

                MeaningList.add(new OvidhanMeaning(enword,bnword));

                englishCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OvidhanMeaning, String>("enword"));
                banglaCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<OvidhanMeaning, String>("bnword"));
                ovidhanTable.setItems(MeaningList);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(MeaningList.size());

        FilteredList<OvidhanMeaning> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(MeaningList, p -> true);
        searchField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            filteredData.setPredicate(person -> {
                if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                    return true;
                }

                String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();

                if (person.getenword().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                    return true; // Filter matches first name.
                }
//                else if (person.getbnword().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
//                    return true; // Filter matches last name.
//                }
                return false; // Does not match.
            });
        });
        SortedList<OvidhanMeaning> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);
        sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(ovidhanTable.comparatorProperty());
        ovidhanTable.setItems(sortedData);
    }

}
```

How should I solve it? How to export and run the jar file properly?

Comment: Your database ("/ankurdb/bn_words.db") needs to a separate file on the filesystem, you can't bundle it as a resource inside your executable jar file.

Comment: so where should i keep? and how should i bundle it?