# Creating a Java Gradle project and building the .jar file in IntelliJ IDEA - How to?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar

Is there a tutorial explaining how to properly create a Java Gradle project and build the .jar file?

When I create a Java project and add Gradle: File -> New -> Module -> Gradle -> ... I receive errors about Java EE websocket's not available (I'm using Ultimate Edition). However, I can successfully create a project by selecting File -> New -> Project-> Gradle -> which gives me a Java project with Gradle that I can debug. However, when I try to create an artifact (.jar file) I receive errors. I assume the errors stem from mistakes I made in the project structure settings.

```
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

or

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

My project is such a mess at this point, maybe I should create another project, then copy/paste the Main.class and Gradle's dependencies from the old project onto the new project.

If this is my best option, how do I correctly create the project this time?

Answer (score 32):

1. Create new Gradle (not Java) project. Be sure to select Java option in the dialog. Click Next.
   [image]

---

2. fill GroupId, ArtifactId and version
   [image]

---

3. Choose your gradle distribution. You can safely use the reccommended option.
   [image]

---

4. Choose project name and location
   [image]

---

5. Click finish

---

6. You put your java classes to src/main/java folder. When using third party libraries, make sure you declare them as Gradle dependencies.
   [image]

---

7. You build your sources using Gradle tab → tasks → build (double click)
   [image]

---

8. You can see the result of the build in the Run tab
   [image]

---

9. In case of error, you can see details by clicking the following button:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer (especially images). However, I get an error:
http://i.imgur.com/gfsAhBD.png

Comment: can you please post the actual console output?

Comment: Did you add gradle dependencies for libraries you are using?

Comment: Try clean task and then build again?

Comment: Also try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Alright! Build successful! Now, where is my .jar file? Is it in <project>/build/libs? I can see there a jar file but its size is only 7 KB.

Comment: yes, the output directory should be build/libs. refer tot his tutorial for creating single jar file http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/

Comment: No matter how I try it outputs 7 KB jar.

Answer (score 14):

Just incase you run into `no main manifest attribute` problem where the executable `Jar` file is not running, I do the following.

> 1: go to your `build.gradle` and add the following at the bottom.

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'your_package_name.YOUR_MAIN_CLASS'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

[image]

> 2. go to `View` > `Tool Windows` > `Gradle`

[image]

> 3. A panel at the right side will be shown, now click the `build` for more task. Under the `build` task double click the `build` option and wait until the task is done.

[image]

> 5. Now, go to your project directory and open the `build` > `libs` and the executable `Jar` file will be there.

I'm not sure if this is the right way.
No need to accept if it works, hope this help the others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Intellij you can just open the Gradle plugin (it is on the right side of your IDE) and execute a command: bootRepackage. With this you will have a jar in: your_project_folder/build/libs.

[image]

Comment: This is Android SDK location setting.

Comment: There is a plugin also for intellij:

Comment: Question is on Java EE. No Android framework is mentioned.

Comment: Yes and the picture is changed and it is for a java project with intellij with gradle.

Comment: mine is a spring boot project, for me bootRepackage option is not showing. gradle assemble works fine(building jar) for me

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Add these lines on your `build.gradle`

```
jar {
from {
    configurations.runtime.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
    configurations.compile.collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
    }
}
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'YOUR MAIN CLASS'
}

exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

**Step 2:** `clean` and `build` .

I'm sure it will work , Regards