# how can I build the jar file of my JavaFX application using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm trying to build a javafx application using gradle but I'm having problems. Gradle creates the jar file, but when I try to run it I get an error:

```
C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\JavaFXTest\build\libs>java -jar JavaFXTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.javafxtest.HelloApplication
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem. The class com.example.javafxtest.HelloApplication exists for me and is located in the correct path. My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Main-Class': 'com.example.javafxtest.HelloApplication'
        )
    }
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.javafxtest'
    mainClass = 'com.example.javafxtest.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.6'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

what can I do to solve this problem?

I tried to use the Intellij Idea build, downloading all the necessary libraries, but it did not lead to any result.

I also found some solution on the Internet, but now it gives a completely different error. I'm trying to open the jar file via java --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-20.0.2\lib --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH -cp JavaFXTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.example.javafxtest.HelloApplication but I get the following error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1082)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
        at javafx.graphics@20.0.2/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: You have gradle rules to use [`org.beryx.jlink`](https://badass-jlink-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) to create a zipped jlink image for distribution, why not use that instead of creating a jar file?  Creating a usable jar file can be problematic, as you have found.   Creating a usable jlink image is likely considerably easier.

Comment: A related colloquy appears in comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77122655/230513).

Comment: @jewelsea I need the output to be an executable jar file. In general, it doesn’t matter to me how it will be created, the main thing is that there is a working jar file. I tried using jlink but again it doesn't work for me. After running jlink, the jlinkbase, image folders were created in the build folder. In the image folder there are several more folders, but in which there are files such as dll, properties, etc. jlinkbase has a jlinkjars folder with jar files, including a jar file with my project name. I ran this jar file with my project name but got the same error I described earlier.

Comment: Solved a problem. Running the jar file works with `java --module-path "C:\javafx-sdk-17.0.8\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.swing -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dprism .verbose=true -jar JavaFXTest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: jlink creates images not jar files. Executable jar files containing JavaFX library code are not supported, though you may get such a setup to work like in this [maven guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing).  There will be an equivalent for Gradle use, though I do not know it.

Comment: This is related https://stackoverflow.com/q/70175403/6395627

Answer (score 0):

You must create a fat JAR.

The following Gradle task creates a fat JAR for a non modular project. Try to include it:

```
task createCustomFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "${mainClassNameParam}"
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

If you do not need your project to be modular, you can download and alter this preconfigured project:

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxAppWithoutModules

**Working alternative:**

You can create a full working non modular Gradle JavaFX Project with this tool:

https://wedasoft.com/projects/javafx-project-generator/

Everything ist preconfigured and you just need to execute the Gradle task `createCustomFatJar` to create a fat JAR.