# Creating Jar with Intellij 2016 - No main manifest attribute

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I am getting `no main manifest attribute` while running the jar create by Intellij. I extracted the jar and observed that there was **another** manifest file, not the one I had specified while creating artifact.

When I open manifest in IDE, it displays everything right but after creating jar I get a whole new manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: YoutubeList
```

I tried every solution from other answers and still not getting it right. Why creating a simple jar is hell of a task in Intellij, it was supposed to help developers!

**Edited**

And sometimes it does not include .class files in Jar which results in `could not found or load class`

Comment: If you have a Maven or Gradle project, the JAR is already created for you when you build and package the project. If you aren't using dependency management, you probably should

Comment: "*When you run `gradle build`, Gradle will compile and test your code, and create a JAR file containing your main classes and resources*" - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html

Comment: I didn't say automatically, I said when you build the project

Comment: Yeah, I mean when you build the project.

Comment: Check "include in project build". See my answer below.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I was stucked with the same problem with maven build.
When you are creating the artifact from project structure settings (ctrl+alt+shift+S), you have to change manifest directory:

```
<project folder>\src\main\java
```

change java to resources

```
<project folder>\src\main\resources
```

I have also used the option extract to the target JAR, and it's working well.

**EDIT**

You can find a detailed step-by-step, an other solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303637/2640826

Comment: I had to tweak jar task in gradle.

Comment: it works for me perfectly. However not able to find the configuration to change the path so From the windows explorar i chaged it.. works Fine..

Comment: I don't know what's up with my IntelliJI IDEA 2017.2.6. But in my the problem appears with /resources folder also. Keeping it as src/META_INF/ worked for me.

Comment: Copied by Jetbrains forum: "Apparently, IntelliJ does not read the manifest file that is located in the src/main/java folder!
Working Solution: As suggested in the ticket, we moved the /META-INF folder to src/main/resources and rebuild the artifact."

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem... I just created a new artifact and changed the folder name before clicking OK.

Comment: IntellijIdea 2018.2 only @Abhishek Saini solution worked.

Comment: I had created a Gradle project using IntelliJ IDEA and official tutorials for generating JAR file didn't help me, I was getting a message "no main manifest attribute" when executing the generated JAR in cmd. This solution worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Comment: For Mac users, `Cmd` + `;` opens project settings

Comment: This worked for me. Interesting solution. Never would have thought to change that. Thanks!

Comment: It worker for me. Thank you!

Comment: intellij 22.1.4 version also works. went through a crazy route to find this...

Answer (score 9):

I spent a few days to resolve it. My solution: I loaded a project that present in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/6837777). Then I compared and corrected settings of the loaded project and my own project. I compared/corrected:

- Run/Debug Configurations
- MANIFEST.MF
- in Progect Structure settings: Project, Modules (mark what is
  sources, resources and etc), Artifacts.

In the end, I placed META-INF in resources directory.

Maybe i did excess actions, but it worked for me :)

P.S. also need to choose "Inherit project compile output path" in Progect Structure settings -> Modules -> Path

[image]

Comment: I was following the steps in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html and stuck at this issue.

I just moved the /META-INF/* folder from /java to /resources directory. This worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

If using Maven, Ensure your pom.xml has the main class referenced and fully qualified, similar to:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.mypkg.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

(... of course the version number of the plugin may be different).

The main class being not fully qualified, is what leads people to suggest moving the manifest to another location (in order to satisfy the reference locally).

Comment: This did not work for me... am I to understand that it's done differently depending on using maven, gradle, ...?

Comment: Didn't help for me too

Comment: Now another error occurs: Error: Could not find or load main class

Answer (score 7):

Putting the META-INF folder in `*/resources` **can do, but is not the way**: Intellij just puts all under `main/resources` or `test/resources` in the root level of the generated jar, that's why it works; but in a Java project, we usually put them under project root, which is the same level as `src`. Putting them under "resources" is breaking the convention, besides, they are not resource files.

Make sure you:

- use the existent `MANIFEST.MF` file at project root;
- the main class is correct
- ticked the `Include in Project build` under "Project structure" -> "Artifacts" panel
- have `META-INF` folder listed in the files to include in the jar, apart from "project compiled output", in the `Output Layout` tab
- the generated file type is JAR, at right top corner

And then, save the settings, **build again**, and enter "Build" menu to "Build Artifacts..", and "build" the JAR. Check the generated jar again, run with `java -jar`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually I solved it by adding the following lines in `build.gradle`

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'class name'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect {
            it.isDirectory()? it: zipTree(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Idea Intellij 2020:**

1. Remove obfuscation if presents
2. delete/(move somewhere outside the project) `META-INF` folder in explorer
3. remove artifacts in project structure--> artifacts--> '-'
4. rebuild the project
5. add artifacts again to project structure--> artifacts--> '+'
6. rebuild the project
7. Build-->Build artifacts..

Now the new produced jar should work

Answer (score 1):

Under `File` / `Project structure` / `Artifacts` you can specify how your jar is to be built. You can chose either to use an existing file as your manifest, or create a new one, in which case you specify main class and class path...

Comment: I did. I specified main class but resulting jar does not contain that manifest file.

Comment: That's the way it's done... Check again that you are building the correct jar, check the settings for it again, perhaps do a clean. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: I read somewhere, if one of your dependent libraries aren't signed, you can't decompress and compress them in the same jar. Try with the other option: "copy to the output directory and link via manifest". By the way, i'm using Intellij IDEA v2016.2.5

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had some dependencies added in my jar, which itself generated a Manifest. I didn't get it to work straight out of Intellij. However, what you can do is open the jar file with a zip program and add the Main class yourself and then copy it back into the jar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**In IntelliJ Idea 2020**

Follow the instructions in this [video](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#get-started).

When you get to the Artifact creation point (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S) change the location of the manifest as shown here. (\src\main\resources)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me, are you using Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

I found a different solution to the ones posted.  In the IntelliJ Project Structure Dialog used to build the contents of the .jar file, I had to manually add the META-INF folder containing the Manifest file.  Here is how it looks at the end in the project structure dialog box. If you don't see the folder in the list of jar contents, then the manifest file is not part of the jar file.

[image: This is part of the Project Structure Dialog box]

The way I include the folder manually is to click the plus sign, select the Directory Content option and then navigate to the META-INF folder.