# IntelliJ doesn't create jar properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, intellij-14

when I try to build my `.jar` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)) I get a `MANIFEST.MF` and a `xml` file inside the `artifacts` folder that's in the `.idea` folder. However I have no `artifact` folder with a `.jar` file inside the `out` folder. That's where the `.jar` file should be. This build process had worked earlier and I have no idea what I messed up.

I really need to build a jar and I used the IntelliJ GUI creator so I can't simply build a jar with an other program because it uses some compiled classes from a IntelliJ library, can I?

### The xml file inside the artifacts folder:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="jar" name="Zimmerbelegung_BwInf36:jar">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/Zimmerbelegung_BwInf36_jar</output-path>
    <root id="archive" name="Zimmerbelegung_BwInf36.jar">
      <element id="directory" name="META-INF">
        <element id="file-copy" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" />
      </element>
      <element id="module-output" name="Zimmerbelegung_BwInf36" />
    </root>
  </artifact>
</component>
```

### My project structure looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: i think you can use maven. it comes with idea and you can simply build .jar. Just recreate maven project using idea, or add [maven pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_intellij_idea.htm) to your existing project

Comment: You could still build it using the jar command line tool if you need to. But Maven would be easier, as suggested by akhambir.

Comment: Have you run "Build | Build Artifact"?

Comment: @y.bedrov Oh thanks this worked. At the first time IntelliJ did this automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ didn't automatically build the artifact.

So I had to build it manually: (`Build` > `Build Artifacts...`)