# "Could not find or load main class" when running a jar file from a msf4j project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, executable-jar, msf4j

I'm working on a Java project which uses the [msf4j](https://github.com/wso2/msf4j) library. In IntelliJ IDEA I'm able to run the project, everything works as expected. However, If I build a jar file from this project (aplying the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303637/1515439) answer), the jar file cannot run (using `java -jar my_jar.jar`). It says:

> Error: Could not find or load main class Main

I've cleaned the project several times, restarted everything, even tried to use older versions of the msf4j, nothing has helped.
If I replace the msf4j with something else (e.g. [javalin](https://javalin.io/documentation)), the built jar file is runnable, the problem goes away.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.msf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>msf4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <microservice.mainClass>src.main.java.Main</microservice.mainClass>
    </properties>

</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

I think the problem is somewhere in the msf4j artifacts. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the top of my head I thing you need to set in maven a project parent and remove the dependency.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.wso2.msf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>msf4j-service</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.2</version>
</parent>
```

HTH,
Gal