# How to create an executable jar file from Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to package up my project into an executable jar using the Intellij IDEA. I followed every step stated in this video [guide video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlyTn8PZ3Fc) and it does create a jar file, but 1. It doesn't contain the necessary resources
2. The output jar file doesn't work, whenever I try to run it by `java -jar Axeereraa.jar` it outputs `no main manifest attribute, Axeereraa.jar`. So how do I make it work?

I've tried googling and following the steps of this answer [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) (and yes I've followed the steps in this solution but it still doesn't work) and I've also changed the place where the META-INF file stored at from `src/main/java` to `src/main/resources` but still the same.

I expect the output to be an executable jar that works not an error.

Comment: I've already tried and failed the steps stated in that link