# How to make jar file with all dependencies a.k.a. Fat jar with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, maven-plugin

I'm trying to make jar file with all dependencies in my project. I'm using IntelliJ.

I tried two ways.

1. In maven window of upper-right part of IntelliJ, I clicked "clean" and "package" with below pom.xml.
   But it doesn't contain any dependencies.
   I'm using IntelliJ in window, so I can't follow below link which is CLI. I'm using GUI maven window in upper right part of IntelliJ.
   [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)
2. I clicked Build-Build artifact - build following below link.
   [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)
   It seems like containing other libraries, but I can't execute this file in some reason. So, please let me use maven window, not build-artifact.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>secret.App</groupId>
  <artifactId>mt</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>mt</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>




  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>com.jungwoo.netmarble.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <filters>
              <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>

                <excludes>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>

                  <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>

                </excludes>
              </filter>
            </filters>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>




        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>


        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.jungwoo.netmarble.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>

            </archive>
          </configuration>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>C:\Users\kimjungwow\Desktop\check5</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42200519/104891

Answer (score 6):

You can use maven assembly plugin. Add following in your pom :

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
</project>
```

Then you execute from command line:

```
mvn package
```

or execute lifecycle goal "package" from intellij

Follow this for more information:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

To get Maven to build a Fat JAR from your project you must include a Fat JAR build configuration in your project's POM file.

Add a plugin to your IntellijIDEA `pom.xml` file:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If you don't know where it is or there isn't at all, here's where to put it or create it:

```
    <build>
    <finalName>my-project-name</finalName>
    <plugins>

/// ADD THE PLUGIN HERE then delete this line ///

     </plugins>
     </build>
```

The Maven command to make Maven build the Fat JAR for your project is:

```
mvn clean package
```

When you execute Maven package phase with the maven-assembly-plugin configuration shown earlier, Maven will output a Fat JAR in the target directory, into which Maven outputs all of its other build products (e.g. compiled classes, generated JavaDocs etc.). The Fat JAR will be named like this:

```
my-project-name-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The part my-project-name of the above Fat JAR file name comes from the finalName XML element included in the top of the build XML element in the example shown earlier in this tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

To build the project simply go to the project directory where you have your pom.xml and then run the following command.

`mvn clean install -DskipTests`