# Intellij Executable Jar - no main manifest attribute Vs Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar

I am developing a small Java application using intellij idea. There is a package and a class. The class runs as expected when outside of the jar format.

I can build a jar and deploy all the dependencies to the same directory and the jar works as expected (I do this with the *copy to the output path and link via manifest* option when configuring a jar build process). However when I try to build a fat jar with all dependencies included in the same jar file, I get one of two errors depending on where the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is positioned: **no main manifest attribute** and **Could not find or load main class**.

Given that the I could get a working jar file if all the dependencies are in the same directory as said jar file, I assumed that the issue was with the classpath.

The`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` contents is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: myPackage.myClass
Class-Path: . myClassJarName.jar
```

When the jar is generated, I see the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`at the root of the structure with the correct information.

Also in the root of the jar is the `myPackage/myClass.class`, corresponding with the manifest file.

I can see all the dependencies in the jar file too.

My projects structure looks like this - note that I have added two manifest lcoations I've tried and the error which comes with each:

```
 .idea 
 out   
   artifacts
     myPackage_jar
       myPackage.jar
 src
   main
     java
       myPackage
         myClass.java
     META-INF <-------------------- *If here, Error: Could not find or load main class err*
       MANIFEST.MF
   META-INF < ------------------ *If here no main manifest attribute err*
     MANIFEST.MF

   test
     java
       myPackage
         myClass.java
 target
   classes
     myPackage
       myClass
   generated-sources
   generated-test-sources
   test-classes
 mypackage.iml
 pom.xml
```

... and its pom file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>myPackage</groupId>
  <artifactId>myPackage</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>anonymise</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>hortonworks</id>
      <name>hortonworks</name>
      <url>https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1000.2.6.2.69-1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The way I configured the jar artifact is:

- Project Structure -> Artifacts
- Click + -> Jar -> From modules with dependencies
- I select the main class as the interface suggests
- Option 'Extract to target Jar'
- I currently have the`META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` Manifest directory set at `src/main` (the full path)
- In the following window, on the left I see all the dependencies of the project. At the bottom of the list, it says `myPackage compile output`

After applying and oking, I generate the jar file to see, as I would expect, that inside there is both the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and the `myPackage/myClass` in the jar root, along with a all the other dependencies. However when I try to run the jar either by:

- `cd` to the location of the jar and use `java -jar myGeneratedJarFilename.jar`
- Use the intellij idea run/debug configuration with the 'application' or the 'run jar application'

The result is the same:

**no main manifest attribute, in myGeneratedJarFilename.jar**

I've tried using the *invalidate caches and restart* several times. I've read several sets of documentation regarding Jars, executable Jars and the Java classpath but I can't find an error.

- I am using `Intellij Idea Community 2020.2`, on Arch Linux.
- Upon typing `java -version` on the terminal I see `openjdk version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14`.
- THe Class-Path in the manifest file is a bit of a mystery to me. The docs say that it is a relative path but relative to what I'm not sure. Any clarifications on that from a pro would be nice!
- The project structure was made using the org.apache.maven quickstark archetype

Can anyone offer any ideas as to what may be the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Fat jars aren't supported: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150485. Please try to use Maven to build it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032993/how-to-make-jar-file-with-all-dependencies-a-k-a-fat-jar-with-intellij

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was using the InteliJ Idea build process to build a fat jar, which is not [supported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150485) in IntelliJ Idea.

To get it working, I updated my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myPackage</groupId>
    <artifactId>myClass</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>myClass</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>hortonworks</id>
            <name>hortonworks</name>
            <url>https://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3.2.6.2.0-205</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1000.2.6.2.69-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>myPackage.myClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Then I had to open the Maven window (View-> Tool Windows -> Maven) and use the Maven tasks `clean` then `compile` then `package` and the jars were created as expected.

Note:

- In my working structure, the MANIFEST.MF is at `src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.
- I did not use any of the IntelliJ project structure Artifacts actions to get the working fat jars. These aren't using Maven, even if you created a Maven project.

Thanks to y.bedrov for the definitive answer when lead to me understanding why it wasn't working.