# Creating Jar file for Java code with Intelij

Tags: java, jar, exe

How can I creat a Jar File of my Java GUI code using Intelij, so I can run my programe and use it like other programes without opening the compiler ?
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link to the same Question which was asked previously on StackOverflow.

[How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)