# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jsoup.nodes.Document.wholeText()Ljava/lang/String;

Tags: selenium, jsoup

I am using JSoup Version 1.12.1. Normally org.jsoup.nodes.Document.wholeText() this is working fine. But when i am creating the artifacts of my project and using this jar file then I am getting this exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jsoup.nodes.Document.wholeText()Ljava/lang/String;

Is any dependencies missed while creating artifacts. To create artifacts I followed
[How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly).

Comment: Where do you use your jar file? Is it a standalone application or is it used by some other service (e.g. a webserver or a M/R Job)

Comment: Hi @TobiSH, i am using this artifacts in selenium to read the email.