# How to easily make a jar file from Intellij and run it correctly?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

1. Making a jarfile throught Intellij Artifacts show me this error when I run the jarfile : `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile Test.jar`
2. Whilst making a jarfile throught Maven assembly plugins show me this when I run the jarfile `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT** : I put META-INF in the right folder and now have `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application` however I make the jarfile. When I launch the program on Intellij everything works fine.

Comment: You made a jar file, you just didn't make a jar file that includes all of the libraries.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? JavaFX was removed from the core JDK since Java 11.

Comment: I'm using java 10.0.2 on intellij and apparently the java in my terminal is 11.0.4

Comment: There's a Maven plug in that packages your executable JAR with all your dependencies.  It's a nice way to manage dependencies, too.  Are you using Maven?  You should be.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes I am using maven, I'm currently reading about how to make a jar with dependencies. Once I make the jar file with all the dependencies, will it runs correctly wherever I run it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

Comment: Thanks, yet I still have the same error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application... It seems like JavaFX is not included in the dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem (thanks to **myself**). Here's the solution if you're using **Maven** and **Intellij**. You can use maven's plugin called **shade**.

1. In **pom.xml**, write this in the plugins section :

   ```
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.2.0</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>shade</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                           <shadedClassifierName>project-classifier</shadedClassifierName>
                           <outputFile>shade${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                           <transformers>
                               <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                   <mainClass>folder.Main</mainClass>
                               </transformer>
                           </transformers>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
   ```
2. Change "folder.Main" by the name of your class containing the main.
3. Go to Run configurations (at the right of the green hammer). Click on the + and Application. Now fill the Main class section by your main class.
4. **Important** : On the bottom of the Run configurations window, there is a green hammer **build**. Just above it, click on the + -> Run Maven goal. In command line, write **clean install**. Click OK.
5. Run your program as you would normally do, using your new Run configuration. There should be a lot of logs on the bottom of intellij, and a new file in the root folder of your project, called shade*your_project_name*.jar
6. To launch it, open a terminal in the jarfile folder, and use java -jar *jarfile*.jar