# How to compile and execute a Java project from the command line?

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to compile and run a java project done in IntelliJ from the command line and I'm a bit perplexed on how to do it. This is my project structure:

```java
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   │   Main.java // Main method's in here.
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   ├───objectclasses
│   │   │   │       Application.java
│   │   │   │
│   │   │   └───utils
│   │   │           Defs.java
│   │   │           Api.java
│   │   │           FileIO.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │           applicationIDs.tmp
│   │           applications.csv
│   │
│   └───test
│       └───java
└───target
    // .class files compiled by IntelliJ
```

Going into the command line, navigating to the `java` directory, and simply typing:

```sh
javac Main.java
```

doesn't work and returns errors saying that all the packages and symbols referred to in the code can't be found. I've also tried navigating to the root directory and running:

```sh
javac -d target -sourcepath src src/main/java/Main.java
```

which returns similar errors. Finally, I tried the following, which outright said "no source files":

```sh
$ javac -d target -sourcepath src -cp .
```

The error that's being returned:

```sh
src\main\java\Main.java:1: error: package objectclasses does not exist
import objectclasses.Application;
                    ^
src\main\java\Main.java:2: error: package utils does not exist
import utils.Defs;
            ^
src\main\java\Main.java:3: error: package utils does not exist
import utils.Api;
            ^
src\main\java\Main.java:4: error: package utils does not exist
import utils.FileIO;
            ^
src\main\java\Main.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    private static void updateApplicationsFile(List<Application> applications)
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Application
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Api api= new Api(
        ^
  symbol:   class Api
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Api api = new Api(
        ^
  symbol:   class Api
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                Defs.API_JSONRPC,
                ^
  symbol:   variable Defs
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                Defs.API_ID,
                ^
  symbol:   variable Defs
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                Defs.API_KEY,
                ^
  symbol:   variable Defs
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                Defs.API_SESSION_ID,
                ^
  symbol:   variable Defs
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                Defs.API_DOMAIN);
                ^
  symbol:   variable Defs
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        List<Application> applications = api.getApplicationsFromIDList(applicationIDs);
             ^
  symbol:   class Application
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
            FileIO.writeIDsToFile(applicationIDs);
            ^
  symbol:   variable FileIO
  location: class Main
src\main\java\Main.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
            FileIO.writeApplicationsToFile(applications);
            ^
  symbol:   variable FileIO
  location: class Main
15 errors
```

I've never done this sort of thing before so I'm probably missing something obvious. Any help?

Comment: If you are using any external libraries as dependencies, they need to be included in the classpath as well. Do you have such dependencies

Comment: I indeed have an external library that I use for handling JSON objects.

Comment: Try and see javac –classpath <path-to-external-jar> <main-class.java>

Comment: This layout looks like a Maven project. Are you sure you don't have a pom.xml for it? Then your command line is `mvn run`.

Comment: This is a Maven project and I can't believe I didn't consider that to be a relevant thing to mention!! My bad. I tried `mvn run` though and it returned an `Unknown lifecycle phase "run".` error.

Comment: Maybe the project does not define how to run it. But you should be able to at least `mvn compile`, and probably also `mvn package` into a jar. Maybe you can run that one, then.

Comment: Managed to get it running @Thilo, see my answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to get the file to run from the command line thanks to Thilo. It was a Maven project, which means that it should be compiled and run via Maven commands. These were the steps I took:

Step 1: Make sure [Maven is installed](https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Step 2: Open the `pom.xml` in the root folder of my project.

Step 3: Add the following plugin to the `<build><plugins></plugins></build>` tags:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Step 4: Navigate to the root folder of the project in the command line.

Step 5: Run `mvn compile` and `mvn package`.

Step 6: Take note of the location of the JAR file in the directory specified in the returned logs. In my case, it was:

`target\App-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Step 7: Run the JAR file with `java -jar target\App-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to specify the path where you have saved your .java file.
if it is in documents(folder) simply write on commande line:

1)**cd documents**
if you have created a folder inside documents then write:

2) **cd foldername**
and then to compile write:

3)**javac (space) your filename along with .java extension.**(javac stand for java compile)
if your project includes a compile-time error it will prompt at this stage.
After compilation you have to write:

4)**java (space) your filename without extension**. because this time we have compile our project. and boom

I used to run my java project this way... but sorry to say I was using notepad not IntelliJ. Hope it helps...
According to your question title the answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps:
 - Export a runnable jar for your project from intellij. Please refer [https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082580/12070280](http://stack%20overflow%20post) on how to do so.
 - Make sure your system Path variable is set to java bin.
 - Navigate to the path where you exported your jar file, and run

```
java myjarfile.jar
```