# Spark Submit command is returning a missing application resource

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

To start things off I created a jar file using this [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly).

My Jar files path is

```
out/artifacts/sparkProgram_jar/sparkProgram.jar
```

My spark program, in general, reads a table from MongoDB, transforms it using spark's mllib and writes it to MySQL.
Here is my build.sbt file.

```
name := "sparkProgram"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"
val sparkVersion = "3.0.0"
val postgresVersion = "42.2.2"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "bintray-spark-packages" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven",
  "Typesafe Simple Repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/simple/maven-releases",
  "MavenRepository" at "https://mvnrepository.com"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  // logging
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.4.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-core" % "2.4.1",
  "org.mongodb.spark" %% "mongo-spark-connector" % "2.4.1",

  //"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.18"
).
```

My main class is in the package com.testing in a scala object named

```
mainObject
```

When I run the following spark-submit command

```
spark-submit --master local --class com.testing.mainObject
--packages mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.12:2.4.1 out/artifacts/sparkProgram_jar/sparkProgram.jar
```

I receive this error

```
Error: Missing application resource.

Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file | R file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:


... zsh: command not found: --packages
```

And then when I attempt to run my spark-submit without the --packages(just to check what would happen) I receive this error.

command:

```
spark-submit --master local --class com.testing.mainObject out/artifacts/sparkProgram_jar/sparkProgram.jar
```

error:
Error: Failed to load class com.testing.mainObject

I've used spark-submit before and it worked ( a couple months back). I'm not sure why this is still giving me an error. My MANIFEST.MF is the following

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.testing.mainObject
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer so far, was to first build the jar file differently.(IntelliJ creation)

`File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Artifacts -> Jar`,
however instead of extracting to jar, I clicked on

```
Copy to Output and link to manifest
```

From there, I did a spark-submit command which did not have --packages part of it.
It was

```
spark-submit --class com.testing.mainObject --master local out/artifacts/sparkProgram_jar/sparkProgram.jar
```

Also be careful about spacing, and copying and pasting into your terminal. White space can give you weird errors.

From there I had another error, which is shown here. https://github.com/Intel-bigdata/HiBench/issues/466. The solution is in the comments

```
"This seems to happen with hadoop 3. I solved it removing a hadoop-hdfs-2.4.0.jar that was in the classpath."
```