# Packaging a Java Swing Application in IntelliJ Idea as a platform independent app

Tags: java, swing, deployment, executable-jar, software-packaging

I've made a small desktop Java Swing App and decided I want to make it readily available for my non-technical friends (or anyone else I want to show it to) to install on their computer (regardless of OS). I'm using Linux Mint. I have come accross a lot of different approaches (Launch4J, JavaPackager and other similar) but I have not succeded. Installed Launch4J but it simply won't load and failed to setup JavaPackager. [This](https://github.com/LeonardoHysesani/PasswordGenerator) is the app. I'm sorry that I'm not able provide specific information, perhaps some of the answers can direct me towards specifying my issue, as I don't know exactly what I have to do and how. I suppose I have to package the jar artifact my IDE has creates (jar artifact works fine in-IDE but I need to "deploy/distribute" the app).

After some more searching I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) and I was able to make my jar executable through the help of @samuelowino 's answer. I'm still not sure if this is platform independent (or you need to install some other jdk to run) so I'm leaving the question open until I make sure.

Comment: Did you try the new jpackage tool? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html

Comment: I''ll try it and update you on the progress.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. my system has openjdk-11 as default. I have to change my jdk to be able to run jpackage right?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure. I am sure that it can compile programs from older java versions, but I do not know if changing your java environment variable is a prerequisite.