# intellj IDEA doesnt build jar properly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly) "tutorial" to build a jar from a project in intellj. The project includes a small spring application, that works running from intellij itself.

If I build the jar and run it from the command line, it says "Error: Could not find or load main class". If I run the main.class file using `java .\main.class`, the same Message shows up.

I specified the Main class in Intellij-IDEA before building the Jar, and the Main.java file looks something like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }


    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
           . . . .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed some test

So I created a new project

[image]

I left the default options

[image]

test with the intellij build

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

not work
[image]

not work
[image]

test with the build provided in spring boot
[image]

[image]

[image]

it works
[image]

Comment: open command prompt, place yourself in the application directory, and run the following command : nvmw package

Comment: it still returns Error: Could not find or load main class demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar. The build was successful

Comment: once the successful configuration is used you do the following command : java -jar .\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> the name must match the name of the file defined in the pom.xml name+version

Comment: ok, thank you! I did some stupid mistakes here, thank you for being so patient!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to tell you that

you can create an order in intellij

[image]

[image]

Change configuration and launch the command from Intellij by pressing the play button
[image]