# Trying to export Intellij project as executable jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to export my Intellij project as an executable jar, but I doesn't find my main class when i try to start it. The only way i found to even start my program is to delete everything from meta-inf except for the manifest file, but then my program can't access a lot of imported libraries. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build jars from IntelliJ properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-properly)

Comment: Are you using any kind of build tool? I didn´t find an option to export a simple java project to an executable jar.

Comment: @mdh you can build a simple Java project into a jar as well

Comment: @Dropout That's the exact post i used for building my jar. What I didnt understand though was, that they wanted me to "You have to change manifest directory:

<project folder>\src\main\java 
replace "java" with "resources"

<project folder>\src\main\resources" So i just didn't do that. ^^

Comment: @Dropout yes for sure but i didn´t find the option by myself. thanks for posting the link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.