# Spring Boot application runs in IntelliJ but doesn't run the from .jar file, and doesn't see profiles

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, executable-jar

I have a Java CRUD application with Spring boot 3, built with database. It's REST functionality application.

The project works when started in IntelliJ IDEA.
Doesn't work and doesn't recognize profiles when I run it from .jar file.

When I finally managed to boot application, I magically deleted the files :/

I get my last version from github, took last running jar version from the recycled bin end extrude it.

I spupose that problem is with dependencies or main Application annotations.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.iseebugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>Trip-Reimbursement-App</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Trip-Reimbursement-App</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Main Class:

```
package pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = {"pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp"}
)
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.adapter"}
)
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = {"pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.model"}
)
public class TripReimbursementAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TripReimbursementAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When i run application in:

- IntelliJ by "Run"
- IntelliJ Terminal by: mvn spring-boot:run

Everythik is Ok. There are connections with database, correct profile and frontend in localhost.

But when i create .jar file and started it
`$ java -jar Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar`
or that:
`$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar`
There are lots of Errors.

I build jar file like in this overflow example:
**[How to build JARs from IntelliJ IDEA properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082580/how-to-build-jars-from-intellij-idea-properly)**

```
$ java -jar Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.1)

23:27:22.240 [main] INFO pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.TripReimbursementAppApplication -- Starting TripReimbursementAppApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 47664 (C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programowanie\Projekty\Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement\Trip-Reimbursement-App\out\artifacts\Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar\Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar started by Lenovo in C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Programowanie\Projekty\Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement\Trip-Reimbursement-App\out\artifacts\Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar)
23:27:22.245 [main] INFO pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.TripReimbursementAppApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
23:27:22.956 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
23:27:23.060 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 90 ms. Found 5 JPA repository interfaces.
23:27:23.485 [main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'receiptTypeController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Programowanie/Projekty/Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement/Trip-Reimbursement-App/out/artifacts/Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar/Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar!/pl/iseebugs/TripReimbursementApp/controller/ReceiptTypeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'receiptTypeService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Programowanie/Projekty/Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement/Trip-Reimbursement-App/out/artifacts/Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar/Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar!/pl/iseebugs/TripReimbursementApp/logic/ReceiptTypeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sqlReceiptTypeRepository' defined in pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.adapter.SqlReceiptTypeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TripReimbursementAppApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
23:27:23.490 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'receiptTypeController' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Programowanie/Projekty/Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement/Trip-Reimbursement-App/out/artifacts/Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar/Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar!/pl/iseebugs/TripReimbursementApp/controller/ReceiptTypeController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'receiptTypeService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Programowanie/Projekty/Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement/Trip-Reimbursement-App/out/artifacts/Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar/Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar!/pl/iseebugs/TripReimbursementApp/logic/ReceiptTypeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sqlReceiptTypeRepository' defined in pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.adapter.SqlReceiptTypeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TripReimbursementAppApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:241)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:464)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1358)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1347)
        at pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.TripReimbursementAppApplication.main(TripReimbursementAppApplication.java:20)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'receiptTypeService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Programowanie/Projekty/Project_23_05_Trip_Reimbursement/Trip-Reimbursement-App/out/artifacts/Trip_Reimbursement_App_jar/Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar!/pl/iseebugs/TripReimbursementApp/logic/ReceiptTypeService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'sqlReceiptTypeRepository' defined in pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.adapter.SqlReceiptTypeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TripReimbursementAppApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:802)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:241)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlReceiptTypeRepository' defined in pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.adapter.SqlReceiptTypeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on TripReimbursementAppApplication: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManager'
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1684)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:689)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
        ... 58 common frames omitted
```

I've tried changing annotations, packages in annotations in many different variants.
I've been changing dependencies like hibernate, hibernate entityManager...
upgreding, downgrading SpringBoot
And i'm lookig for the mistake a long time on many different portals.

Comment: The first problem: `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.logic.ReceiptTypeService' available: expected at least 1 bean which` second why defining several deps with versions... SB offers them... Best would be to use most recent version of SB (3.2.1)...

Comment: Ah most important... Maven profiles are not related to spring boot profiles... Maven profiles are intended for build time ... which spring profiles are intended for run time... they can be defined on command line via `java -jar artifact --spring.profiles.active=dev`...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have version wich work but only .jar file where it worked. When i run it with '$ java -jar Trip-Reimbursement-App.jar' everythink is ok. Profile is loading, and there are no errors in logs.

Comment: You sseem to need a bean from the `pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.logic.ReceiptTypeService` package, but have set the base package to scan for beans to `pl.iseebugs.TripReimbursementApp.controller`; you will need to adjust the baseScanPackages